# How and when do Javascript global anonymous functions get invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I see something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”css/bootstap.min.css”>
</head>
<body>
<span class=”btn btn-success fileinput-button”>
    <i class=”glyphicon glyphicon-plus”></i>
    <input id=”fileupload” type=”file” name=”files[]” multiple>
</span>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src=”js/bootstrap.min.js”></script>
<script>
$(function () {

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How and when does the anonymous function get invoked on the html page?

I don’t understand how this works.  I am not completely ignorant of javascript, but I have seen this many times and I would like to know how it works.

I have also seen in .js files:

```
(function (factory) {

}(function($) {
});
```

Perhaps someone can help me understand what the semantics of these mean?

Comment: `$(function () { ... });` is simply a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`, and it is not a self-invoking anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks Terry.  So this is because it is using jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript top-level statements simply get executed in order when the script is loaded. In your first example, there's just one statement, a call to the function named `$`. Calling `$(function() {...})` is equivalent to calling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

So it declares that the anonymous function will be executed when the DOM is ready.

Your second example is an IIFE (Immediately-Executing Function Expression). It defines a function that takes `factory` as an argument, and calls that function with the anonymous function as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you Barmar.  So are you saying that the function($) is taking the function( factory ) as the argument?

Comment: No, it's the other way around. `function($)` is the argument to `function(factory)`. Arguments to a function come **after** the function, e.g. in `alert(thing)` the function is `alert` and the argument is `thing`.

Answer (score 0):

• $(function () {

});
is same as 
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });

This Function is called when the DOM is ready which means, you can start to query elements for instance. .ready() will use different ways on different browsers to make sure that the DOM really IS ready.

•(function(){ ... })();

That is nothing else than a function that invokes itself as soon as possible when the browser is interpreting your ecma-/javascript. Therefor, its very unlikely that you can successfully act on DOM elements here.